# regexp_extract arguments in Hive

Tags: regex, apache, hadoop, hive

What does the argument in the curly brackets do in the following segment of code?

```
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*)\,?){1}', 1) Id,  
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*)\,?){2}', 1) Score,  
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*)\,?){9}', 1) DisplayName,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), curly brackets contain how many times the preceding token, in this case a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap), may repeat.

The group contains a (possibly empty) [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) made of non-comma characters, followed by an optional comma. Since there is only one number in curly brackets, the non-capturing group must repeat exactly that number of times.

I don't know why the comma should be escaped by a backslash. It seems to me that the backslash is not necessary.

Caveat: I don't know Hadoop or Hive, all my knowledge of `regexp_extract` comes from [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF).

The purpose of these regexes is to match the first, second and ninth element in a comma-separated list, where the capturing group #1 (selected by the third argument of `regexp_extract`) returns only its last occurrence. Of course the comma is not really optional, except after the last element.

Comment: Thanks Walter, so if I understand you correctly it's somewhat similar to the col_index_num in a vlookup in Excel? So in the case above it is pulling all contents from the 1st, 2nd and 9th columns in the original file and storing them in the new file?

Comment: @WolfPig in this case yes, I presume (I have no visibility beyond those three lines)